# How to mass add text to existing content via single formula

Tags: mysql

I currently have an existing Wordpress directory website consisting of 20K city posts. I would like to update the first line of each post to include some text and an image. Each post should have its own unique image.

I am looking for a way to mass enter this into the database.

Tried using a few plugins but none are doing this effectively.

The mysql database has a column called "post_name" which has the city info for each post in "city-state" format. There is also the post title under "post_title" which could be useful for the image alt text. I would like to tap into this to point to the specific city images.

For example:

```
<img src="/city-state.gif">Post Title</ >
```

The content for the post sits in "post_content."

So ideally, I would like to create some code that adds this new content to all "post_content" cells from by using "post_name" so URLs are entered in based on that.

Example:

New static text that won't change for any posts.

```
<img src="/'post_name'.gif">'post_title'</ >
```

Is something like this possible?

Comment: Which mysql version are you using REGEXP_REPLACE could do the trick, but it needs mysql 8.x

Comment: Server version: 5.6.45 - MySQL Community Server (GPL)